# Can Server 2012R2 DHCP support a second gateway for subset of clients?

Tags: windows, dhcp

I have one subnet with Server 2012R2 DC.  It is also my DHCP.  I have two locations, primary location has ~50 clients, satellite location has 4 clients.  We just upgraded to fiber at both locations with an Ethernet Private Line between the two locations.  The Primary location has 50M fiber, the Satellite has 25M fiber. We also have a dedicated 10M Ethernet Fiber Line between the two locations.

The primary location has Fiber Connection 1 with LAN 192.168.100.x/24 and Gateway 192.168.100.1.  The satellite location has its own Fiber Connection 2 and shares the same LAN 192.168.100.x/24 but with Gateway 192.168.100.2.

The Ethernet Private Line connects between Primary and Satellite locations and provides a dedicated Fiber Connection 3 that allows both locations to use the same subnet.  When the DHCP server handles all clients the 4 clients in the satellite office currently receive the Primary location Gateway (192.168.100.1).  Therefore, when a Satellite client access the internet, they go through the Primary Gateway and therefore the Primary Fiber Connection 1.

I have confirmed all of this using speedtest.net.  From the Primary location internet speeds are the rated 50Mbps.  From the Satellite location internet speeds come in at 10Mbps (rate limited by the dedicated fiber speed).

The Satellite clients are receiving DHCP IPs from the DHCP server.  I can access the server(s) in the Primary location with no problem.

As a workaround, I have reserved 4 IP addresses in the DHCP Server so I can use those static IPs on the Satellite cleints with Gateway 192.168.100.2.  With this workaround, I can still access the servers at the Primary location.  When I run a speedtest on the Satellite clients I get the expected 25Mbps. This gives me a proof of concept but is somewhat fragile with the Static IPs.

Is there a way to configure the DHCP server to issue DHCP IPs to the Satellite cleints but with the Statellite Gateway 192.168.100.2?

Possibly a Satellite OU for the Satellite clients where I could assign the Satellite Gateway to the Satellite OU?

Comment: You have both sites on the same subnet... Why

Comment: Satellite clients need access to Server apps.  It was previously configured with VPN with relatively slow internet at Satellite office..  Ethernet Private Line eliminates a lot of VPN overhead.

Comment: You can use differents subnet without the need of vpn... please split that site in its own subnet and add the correct routing rule in the remote router.

Comment: The Private line should be a /30 & /127 or /64 as well.